# In puppeteer how to wait for DOM element to load and then click

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

In puppeteer how to wait for DOM element to load and then click. I am trying access a simple page, hit the **Start** button and then a text field should appear, and I need to type in that text field.

Code given as below.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sleep = (waitTimeInMs) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, waitTimeInMs));

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html');
  await page.click('#start', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
  //await sleep(5000);
  await page.type('#username', 'austin');
  await sleep(5000);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

However if I put a sleep of 5 second (commented in above code), then I am able to type in text field.

I want to avoid giving sleep. Please suggest what's the work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wait for the element to be visible because the element is present in the DOM, but not visible.

Here is the script that works:

```js
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/videocalltest.html');
    await page.click('#start');
    await page.waitForSelector('#username', { visible: true });
    await page.type('#username', 'austin');
    // await browser.close(); // commented it just to make sure that text is typed in the input before close browser.
})();
```

Comment: This works perfect. If I launch chrome with  {headless: true}, will  waitForSelector with  { visible: true } option work?

Comment: how does the waitForSelector handles error? what happens if the selector is not loaded?

Comment: @MirzaPayam
The `waitForSelector` function will throw If the selector doesn't appear after the timeout(Defaults to 30000 (30 seconds)) milliseconds of waiting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ;[`page.waitForSelector(selector[, options])`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.8.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options):

```
await page.waitForSelector('#username', {visible: true})
```

Comment: Tried this. Still same issue. It does not type in text field.

Comment: I was just missing await at start of line. Your solution also works.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Errors

await page.waitForSelector('#username', {visible: true})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('success');
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Also, don't combine `await` and `then()`. Choose a paradigm and stick with it. Also, this does not seem to add anything over [the previous answer a year prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57282821/215552)